# How can I unlock KDE Wallet automatically on nixos?

Tags: kde, nixos

I decided to start using kwallet since it comes with kde on nixos. I would like to set it up to unlock automatically though. On the arch linux wiki there is a section that covers this here [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE_Wallet). But how can I do this on nixos? Should I use the configuration.nix or /etc/pam.d/kde?

Comment: Same question about GNOME Keyring.

Comment: Try upgrading to NixOS 18.03 and set `security.pam.services."your_display_manager".enableKwallet = true`.

Comment: `/etc/pam.d` contains only symlinks to generated files in the nix store. Don't edit those.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using plasma5 I believe this is already enabled.

You can use the [`security.pam.services.<name?>.enableKwallet`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#enablekwallet) option.

Add to your config:

```
security.pam.services.kwallet = {
  name = "kwallet";
  enableKwallet = true;
};
```

This will add the neccesary pam entry in `/etc/pam.d`

```
$ cat /etc/static/pam.d/kwallet

# Account management.
account sufficient pam_unix.so

# Authentication management.

auth required pam_unix.so  likeauth

auth optional /nix/store/llds2sy99zg92lrk9gsfzhpz7f6wnxdy-kwallet-pam-5.8.6/lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so kwalletd=/nix/store/x9q0g102hlxx60jb332xmdpq76ia1bja-kwallet-5.31.0/bin/kwalletd5
auth sufficient pam_unix.so  likeauth try_first_pass

auth required pam_deny.so

# Password management.
password requisite pam_unix.so nullok sha512

# Session management.
session required pam_env.so envfile=/nix/store/5ninxpd3cmysfzlhij1afymd0gyg7x0p-pam-environment

session required pam_unix.so

session optional /nix/store/llds2sy99zg92lrk9gsfzhpz7f6wnxdy-kwallet-pam-5.8.6/lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so kwalletd=/nix/store/x9q0g102hlxx60jb332xmdpq76ia1bja-kwallet-5.31.0/bin/kwalletd5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `security.pam.services` to set this up. something along this lines

```
security.pam.services = [
  { name = "kde";
    text = ''
      auth            optional        pam_kwallet.so kdehome=.kde4
      session         optional        pam_kwallet.so
    '';
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried it and got this error in the kdm.log

klauncher(993) kdemain: No DBUS session-bus found. Check if you have started the DBUS server. 
kdeinit4: Communication error with launcher. Exiting!
kdmgreet(987)/kdecore (K*TimeZone*): KSystemTimeZones: ktimezoned initialize() D-Bus call failed:  "Not connected to D-Bus server" 

kdmgreet(987)/kdecore (K*TimeZone*): No time zone information obtained from ktimezoned 
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch

Comment: I have the same question about GNOME Keyring.  Is the procedure documented somewhere?