# How to unlock GNOME keyring automatically in NixOS?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-keyring, nixos

I am using GNOME 3 on NixOS 16.09, and I cannot figure out how to make the "Login" keyring unlock automatically on login.

I suspect this could be fixed with the [`security.pam.services`](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-security.pam.services) option, but I am not an expert, and the documentation is not very verbose or clear:

> This option defines the PAM services. A service typically corresponds to a program that uses PAM, e.g. **login** or **passwd**.  Each attribute of this set defines a PAM service, with the attribute name defining the name of the service.
>
> *Type:* list or attribute set of submodules
>
> *Default:* `[ ]`

A related but less important issue is that if I create a new user account under NixOS and log in with GNOME, no keyring is automatically created.  The first time I enter a password somewhere and accept to save it in a keyring, I get a dialogue asking for a password to create a new default keyring:

> Choose password for new keyring
>
> An application wants to create new keyring called 'Default keyring'.  Choose
>   the password you want to use for it.

Note that it wants to create a keyring called "Default keyring", and not "Login", like Ubuntu does.

If I type in my login password, the keyring is created, but on the next login it is not unlocked automatically, and I am asked for a password the first time I try to use it.

---

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280706/54221) is an analogous question about KDE Wallet, which so far has no accepted answer.

---

There is a relevant [issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/21859) reported for Nixpkgs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is [fixed](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/61450) in 19.03. If the login manager is GDM, then set the [configuration option](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#enablegnomekeyring)

```nix
{ # ...
  security.pam.services.gdm.enableGnomeKeyring = true;
}
```

It has been suggested that if no login manager is used, then the following option needs to be set:

```nix
{ # ...
  services.gnome3.gnome-keyring.enable = true;
}
```

Comment: Can the `name` be `sddm`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, i don't know, and i am not using NixOS anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`security.pam.services.<name?>.text`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#security.pam.services.<name?>.text) option.

Add to your config:

```
pam.services = [
  { name = "gnome_keyring"
    text = ''
      auth     optional    ${gnome3.gnome_keyring}/lib/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so
      session  optional    ${gnome3.gnome_keyring}/lib/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start

      password  optional    ${gnome3.gnome_keyring}/lib/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so
    '';
  }
];
```

This will add the neccesary pam entry in `/etc/pam.d`

```
$ cat /etc/static/pam.d/gnome_keyring

auth     optional    /nix/store/ffcm7771dvva2xs56dzp6avxzf0pg35x-gnome-keyring-3.20.0/lib/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so
session  optional    /nix/store/ffcm7771dvva2xs56dzp6avxzf0pg35x-gnome-keyring-3.20.0/lib/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start

password        optional        /nix/store/ffcm7771dvva2xs56dzp6avxzf0pg35x-gnome-keyring-3.20.0/lib/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

Comment: I tried, but the keyring is still locked on login.  Does this work for you?  There is a [bug report](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/21859) about this problem for GDM (i have it with LightDM).

Comment: You also need to use the same password for your keyring as your login I believe. It works on mine with sddm.

Comment: Which desktop manager are you using?  From SDDM i cannot even log into a GNOME 3 session.

Comment: I'm using KDE Plasma 5.

Comment: I have just tried with Plasma 5 and SDDM, but still i have to unlock GNOME's "Login" keyring manually each time. The password for Login keyring is the same as for the account. Strange. Thanks for the answer and for the comments anyway.

Comment: Could you tell me please if by any chance there are some packages to be installed for this to work?  I noticed that there quite a few PAM related packages, but i do not have any of them installed, not even `linux-pam`.

Comment: Looking at the arch wiki [section on the GNOME keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#Automatic_login), for GDM your keyring will only be unlocked automatically if it's name is 'login'. I would delete your keyring and remake it under the name 'login'. It also won't work if you are using passwordless login as it needs your password to be typed in to unlock to your keyring.

Comment: I don't still have it setup to automatically unlock my keyring, but when I did make it work I followed the arch Wiki.

Comment: I'm using SLiM and haven't been able to get this working either. Has anyone had any success?